# TeX Gyre Heros stacked accents in headings

Tags: fonts, sectioning, accents

I'm trying to stack accents in my section titles with TeX Gyre Heros. When I use the code I employ in my body text though (`\'{\"{u}}`), the accents don't stack properly.

I looked into the [TeX Gyre Heros technical documentation](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/qhv-info.pdf) and found the following information on page 10, in the font's repertoire of glyphs:

```
1E2F ḯḯḯḯ idieresisacute
```

- "1E2F" is the unicode number.
- "idieresisacute" is the OTF name.

However, I don't know how to use that information to make my code work.

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For links' color
\usepackage{colortbl} % To define colors
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

% HEADING and PART FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\partfont[]{Candara}

% HEADER AND FOOTER STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\headingfont \leftmark}
%\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Guides and tutorials}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\headingfont \thepage}
%\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%%%

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\color{black}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\color{black}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\color{black}\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}

\begin{document} 

\'{\"{u}}

\subsection{\'{\"{u}}}

\section{\'u}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command uses a base glyph with a combining accent, and the font doesn't handle this well. But the font has the LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND ACUTE (U+01D8) and you can use it by inputing its unicode value or by using the glyph directly.

The harfbuzz renderer does this conversion automatically and so handles also the accent command better. To use this renderer you need a current tex system and must use `lualatex-dev` to compile.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Renderer=Harfbuzz] %

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\'{ü}\quad ü\char"0301 \quad u\char"0308\char"0301 \quad \char"01D8 \quad  ǘ

\sffamily

\'{ü}\quad ü\char"0301 \quad u\char"0308\char"0301 \quad \char"01D8 \quad  ǘ

\end{document}
```

[image]